# Locate database does not exist, even though it is already loaded

Tags: macos

I am trying to use the locate command because even though I installed postgresql, psql is not recognized on command line:

```
$ locate psql | grep /bin

WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate; once
the database has been created, this message will no longer appear.
```

So I run the command:

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist
com.apple.locate: Already loaded
```

Output:

```
$ ls -l /var/db/locate.database
-r--r--r--  1 nobody  wheel  11096658 Mar 25 14:29 /var/db/locate.database
```

If it is already loaded, then why is it telling me to create the database? I already created it. How can I get locate working?

Comment: *Please be aware that the database can take some time to generate*. Also, can you add the output of `ls -l /var/db/locate.database`  to the question?

Comment: @patrix I added the output

Comment: Hi Donato, I'm experiencing the same problem with Sierra. My system started with Mavericks long ago however.

Comment: Daniel, @Tmanok How did you solved the problem with the locate database?

Answer (score 9):

You can update the database used by `locate` manually by running

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Here is what I did to make it work.

1. Recreate the db

```
$ sudo touch /var/db/locate.database
```

2. Change owner and group of the new file

```
$ sudo chown nobody /var/db/locate.database
$ sudo chgrp wheel  /var/db/locate.database
```

3. Change permissions on database.

```
$ sudo chmod u+w /var/db/locate.database
```

4. launch update of Locate DB.

```
$ sudo -u nobody /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```

5. Check that the file has been updated

```
$ ls -als /var/db | grep "locate"
```

You should have a line in result with a locate.database file with a non null size :

```
44032 -rw-r--r--    1 nobody                  wheel                   21513758 Jan 15 15:29 locate.database*
```